# Remote MySqli Connection timeout only while connecting via Apache2

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, mysqli, mariadb

I am facing a problem on **Ubuntu 18.04 Apache EC2 Machine/Server - 172.2.27.1** that mysqli is not getting connected there to **MariaDB Server - 172.2.27.2** (remote mysqli server), but it gets connected via localhost (as currently 172.2.27.1 machine has MariaDB installed on it as well), also the remote connection to 172.2.27.2 is establishing over the **Terminal**:

`mysql -h 172.2.27.2 -u test -p` (on 172.2.27.1 Machine)

Unable to understand what could be the exact issue for it. I have tried debugging all possible locations but couldn't find any.

While connecting with Apache it is giving error:

```
Object
(
    [affected_rows] => 
    [client_info] => 
    [client_version] => 50012
    [connect_errno] => 2002
    [connect_error] => Connection timed out
    [errno] => 
    [error] => 
    [error_list] => 
    [field_count] => 
    [host_info] => 
    [info] => 
    [insert_id] => 
    [server_info] => 
    [server_version] => 
    [stat] => 
    [sqlstate] => 
    [protocol_version] => 
    [thread_id] => 
    [warning_count] => 
)
```

PS: There are no firewall rules issue neither on Machine nor on EC2 instance. I have already checked that. All available code to connect to remote MariaDB server on the internet is giving the same result. Its not a code issue, maybe some apache extension issue or PHP's. Server 172.2.27.1 is not able to connect to any other MariaDB server on the internet. It's only working on localhost, not anything else.

Comment: Can you share more details? What have you tried to debug the problem, like: show the code you are using? Show the debugging attempts?

Comment: All available code to connect to remote MariaDB server on the internet is giving the same result. Its not a code issue, maybe some apache extension issue or PHP's. Server 172.2.27.1 is not able to connect to any other MariaDB server on the internet. It's only working on localhost, not anything else.

Comment: Can you please share what exact error you are getting or share screenshot of error?

Comment: Have you tried with PDO?

Comment: Could you please check if you have correct Database IPs and port set in code?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably Firewall rules are blocking your connection: (Connection timed out)

Check the `Security groups` assigned to the Mysql/MariaDB instance, and make sure `Mysql port (3306)` is allowed properly on the MariaDB setup, to accept `inbound` connections from `172.2.27.2` specifically, or from the whole subnet.

Comment: There I have *All Traffic allowed* and hence I am able to connect Mysql of 172.2.27.2 via Terminal on 172.2.27.1. Only its issue with Apache's PHP file its not getting connecting.

Comment: There is no way PHP is blocking it. Apache is doing an Outbound connection towards your Mysql box, so unless you have some Outbound rules on the EC2's end that block outbound connections (which I doubt, as they are permitted by default), but you can still check, I see no reason why the connection should be blocked. I also do not know your exact setup, so this could be hard to pinpoint from my point of view. Are both the EC2 and Mysql in the same VPC? Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't configured your DB for remote address.
set my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
skip-networking=0
skip-bind-address
```

Then set mysql.user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'172.2.27.%' 
  IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Restart all processes afterwards
Look at this for reference:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/